Should an info banner close automatically on page refresh or only when the user actively closes it?
everyone!
I'm designing a CRM dashboard where users can list items for sale. The process involves our internal team verifying the product and information before it's published online. To communicate this, I've created an info banner that appears after users submit their product for validation.
My question is: should we keep this banner at the top of the product list until users intentionally close it, or hide it after a page refresh? It's worth noting that we also use a notification messaging system where this message will be displayed.


Does the banner block any primary actions? If not, you have a dismiss action and clearly state that the system is processing some information. I'd recommend leaving it until the user dismisses it, or until the process shown is complete.

This is where you need to align with (or come up with) a system for handling notifications within the software, rather than making a decision about a single type of banner in isolation to other types of messaging that happens within the application. You already mentioned about another notification messaging system that is used, which means that there are also rules for implementing them that exist.
A typical way to look at notification design is to consider the following factors:

Urgency or how soon the user needs to act on it
Importance/Severity or how critical it is for the user to act on it
Persistence/Relevance or how long will the issue applicable to act on

Then you can look at other considerations for the actual banner design, which includes all the visual styling in its presentation and organization of content (for example, what to do with multiple notifications of the same or different type).
So even though you have asked a simple question about the expected behaviour of the info banner, the answer should either already exist somewhere within the design or implementation documentation; or there are gaps that you need to work through and fill in as part of designing this component (for this use case).

Looking at the design, it seems to me that the product is listed, with status "Validation". If that's correct, I'd reduce the notification to this combination:

Show a transient "toast" saying the product has been saved and submitted for validation.
Make the status interactive (hover or click) to display the explanation shown in the notification design.

Rationale:

The notification as-is takes up a lot of space, which might push other information below the fold.
Everyone doing this the second time will know how it works (here, I am assuming things about your target group - be sure that is correct - you didn't talk about your target group).
The user needs to acknowledge the notification to regain the space.
The current notification design raises additional questions like the one you asked, and this complicates the user interaction and the implementation.

